# Return from a function and reset its variables on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The page with the problem: http://robinbz216.216.axc.nl/kinderen.html

I open a modal on click and get different content in the modal for each of the 11 divs you can click on. I made a left and right arrow so users dont have to close the modal and click the next div to view the next content. When a div is clicked, jquery looks for it position in a nodelist of all the 11 items, puts that in a variable (named indexVar) and get the right content out of the 11 content arrays. If you click the left arrow, indexVar gets -1, and then that number again get checked with the content arrays and the previous div content is shown in the modal.

This all works fine the first time you click a div. But when you close the modal, and click again on a div, the last indexVar has not disappeared and another instance of the same click function is made and so it doubles the next previous 
and next clicks that are done with the arrow buttons.

I guess my function structure is pretty bad, and i dont know how to fix it so that with a second click on one of the 11 divs, it starts fresh without the functions from the last modal use.

```
$(".kindDiv").click(function() {
  if (!($("#singleModal2").hasClass("zichtbaar"))) {
    $("#singleModal2").addClass("zichtbaar");


    // Returns a NodeList
    var kindDivss = document.getElementsByClassName("kindDiv");

    var indexVar = $(".kindDiv").index(this);

    var modalLength = modalArray.length;

    var modalLengthMin = modalLength;
    var modalLengthMini = modalLength;

    modalLengthMini = modalLengthMini - 1;
    modalLengthMin = modalLengthMin - 2;


    for (i = 0; i < modalLength; i++) {
      var firstWord = modalArray[i].replace(/ .*/, '');
      arrayVoornaam.push(firstWord);

      if (i == indexVar) {
        //append content in modal
        $("#singleModal2 h4").html(arrayVoornaam[i]);
        $("#singleModal2 p").html(modalArray[i]);
        $("#singleModal2 img").attr("src", imageArray[i]);
      }
    }

    //Hide buttons when first or last of 11 divs is opened
    if (indexVar == modalLengthMini) {
      $(".arrowRight").addClass("invisible");

    }
    if (indexVar == 0) {
      $(".arrowLeft").addClass("invisible");

    }

    //Left arrow click
    $(".arrowLeft").click(function() {
      if (indexVar == 1) {
        $(".arrowLeft").addClass("invisible");

      }
      if (indexVar !== modalLengthMin) {
        $(".arrowRight").removeClass("invisible")

      }
      indexVar--;

      $("#singleModal2 h4").html(arrayVoornaam[indexVar]);
      $("#singleModal2 p").html(modalArray[indexVar]);
      $("#singleModal2 img").attr("src", imageArray[indexVar]);

    });


    //Right arrow click
    $(".arrowRight").click(function() {
      if (!indexVar == 1) {
        $(".arrowLeft").removeClass("invisible");
      }
      if (indexVar == modalLengthMin) {
        $(".arrowRight").addClass("invisible");

      }
      indexVar++;

      $("#singleModal2 h4").html(arrayVoornaam[indexVar]);
      $("#singleModal2 p").html(modalArray[indexVar]);
      $("#singleModal2 img").attr("src", imageArray[indexVar]);
    });




    //close modal
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $("#singleModal2").removeClass("zichtbaar");
      arrayVoornaam = [];

      $(".arrowLeft").removeClass("invisible");
      $(".arrowRight").removeClass("invisible");
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Is bad practice adding event listeners inside other event handlers. That is why you get multiple listeners firing. Could try quick fix using `off()` before adding new one ... `$(".arrowRight").off('click').click(function....`

Comment: In order to prevent multiple attachment of the same event listener, You can attach even to the modal's parent once using the delegate() method( http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ ) which will listen to the children's event inside it all the time.

Comment: Thanks guys, the "off()" was a nice easy fix.